# Activity Monitor and System Profiler won't report 32 bit apps

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, 64-bit, system-profiler

I'm trying to check which apps I am going to lose when I upgrade to Big Sur. According to numerous websites I should be able to do this via Activity Monitor or System Profiler.

Activity monitor should have column on the CPU tab to show Kind, but it isn't there and the menu to add columns doesn't include it.

System Profiler should have a column for "64 big (intel)" but it doesn't and I can't see any options for adding/removing columns there.

[image]

OS X 10.15.7
MacBook Pro 15-inch 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for 32-bit apps was already removed in 10.15 Catalina.

It would make sense that Activity Monitor would no longer have that column since no such apps can run. It looks like that column was also removed from System Report.

So the good news is you probably don't have anything that broke, or at-least you haven't missed them if they did.

If you still want to check for any lingering 32-bit apps, you can probably still do so [using mdfind in Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314462/70505).

Comment: Ah, I thought Big Sur was a big change since I am getting warnings about things not being compatible with future versions of OS X.

Comment: @Craig Those warnings might be from kernel extensions.